# Does $\#_n S^2×S^1$ really admit a map of non-zero degree from $B×S^1$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds

In Proposition 4 on page 6 of this paper, http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.6302, the authors claim to produce a degree 2 $\pi_1$-surjective map $f$ between $M=S^1 \times \Sigma_2$ and $N=\#_2 S^2 \times S^1$ (the connected sum of two copies of S^2 \times S^1). I cannot follow their construction and I seem to have quickly convinced myself that such a map is impossible. The fundamental group of $N$ is a free group $\mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z}$ which has no non-trivial center. Letting $h$ be the generator of $\pi_1(S^1)$, this implies that $f_*(h \times 1)= 1$. Consider the abelianized map $$ f_* : H_1(M) \to H_1(N)$$ Then $f_*([h \times 1])=0$. Which means that  the image of $$ f^*:H^1(N) \to H^1(M)$$ vanish on $[h \times 1]$. Now write the generator $ \alpha_3 \in H^3(N)$ as a product of elements $\alpha_1 \cup \alpha_2$ with $\alpha_i \in H^i(N)$. However we then obtain that $f^*(\alpha_3)=0=f^*(\alpha_1) \cup f^*(\alpha_2)=0$. To see this observe that $f^*(\alpha_1)$ vanishes on $[h \times 1]$ and thus under the identification of $H^1(S^1\times \Sigma_2)=\mathbb{Z}[h \times 1]^* \oplus H^1(\Sigma_2)$ has no component in $\mathbb{Z}[h \times 1]^*$...

EDIT: As Jim Conant and Igor Belegradek pointed out, my error is in the deduction that the cup-product must be zero just because this component vanishes. $f^*(\alpha_1)$ could be a generator in $[1 \times \pi_1(\Sigma_2)]^*$ and f^*(\alpha_2) could be of the form $[h \times 1]^* \otimes H^1(\Sigma_2)$. Thanks very much to them.

Does this make sense or am I making a mental error?

Moreover any subgroup of a free group is free and I think this would imply that there is no map between the two manifolds of non-trivial degree. What am I missing?

Comment: Cross-posted as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742500/does-n-s2-times-s1-really-admit-a-map-of-non-zero-degree-from-b-times since I wasn't sure which level the question was.

Comment: Where do the authors make such a claim?

Comment: Why is $\alpha_3$ a product of low-dimensional classes? Also how does vanishing of $f^*(\alpha_1)$ on the central circle imply vanishing on all loops?

Comment: Ok, $\alpha_3$ is indeed the product of classes dual to the summands of $S^1\vee S^2$ in $N$. What about the other question?

Comment: @Igor Belegradek For the first question, because it is true for $S^2 \times S^1$ and because of the usual formula for the cohomology of connected sum? For the second question, that is not my claim. My claim is that by inspecting the cohomology ring of $M$, it is impossible for a product of that form to be non-trivial--- any non-trivial product to H^3 must has a component in the dual of the central circle.

Comment: I don't see why $f^*(\alpha_1)=0$. You say $\alpha_1$ vanishes on $[h\times 1]$ by which you mean $f^*(\alpha_1)$ vanishes on $[h\times 1]$, but as Igor mentions, why must it vanish on all loops in $M$?

Comment: Triviality of the center does not necessarily imply $f_*(h\times 1)=0$. One might instead have $f_*(1\times \pi_1\Sigma_2)=0$.

Comment: @JimConant and Igor you are both right sorry for my silliness.

Comment: @ThiKu I have looked at the paper. The way the map for $n=2$ is constructed it seems that indeed, $\pi_1(S^1)$ is mapped to the neutral element $e$. If the surface group is represented as $\langle a,b,c,d\mid aba^{-1}b^{-1}cdc^{-1}d^{-1}\rangle$, then $a$, $c$ map to generators of $F_2$, and $b$, $d$ map to $e$. Of course, this does not automatically follow from the group structures.