# Is there a degree one map from a product $B\times S^1 \to \#_n S^2 \times S^1$ for any n

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds

For any $n \geq 1$, let $\Sigma_n$ denote the closed orientable surface of genus n. In http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.6302, the authors showed that for any $n$, there is a degree *two*, $\pi_1$-surjective, map $ f: S^1 \times \Sigma_n \to \#_n S^1 \times S^2$ (the $n$-fold connected sum).

Question: For any $n \geq 2$, is it possible to produce a possibly different closed orientable surface $B$ together with a degree *one* map $f': S^1 \times B \to \#_n S^1 \times S^2 $ ?

For $n=1$ of course it is possible to (for example) set $B=S^2$ and find a degree one map (the identity).

Comment: This is related to (but different from) [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/236233/70808).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find such a map which is degree one. The cut number $n$ of a closed 3-manifold $M$ is the maximal number of 2-sided disjointly embedded surfaces $\Sigma_1,\ldots,\Sigma_n$ which do not separate $M$. For each connected surface $\Sigma_i$, we can make a degree one map to the 2-sphere by taking a spine of the surface (a embedded graph whose complement is a disk) and crushing it to a point. Do this for each component of the surfaces $\Sigma_i$ in the 3-manifold mapping to $S^2\times \ast$ for each factor of $\#_n S^2\times S^1$. The complement of these 2-spheres is a $2n$-punctured 3-sphere. There is no obstruction to extending the maps of $\cup_n \Sigma_i$ to $\cup_n S^2\times \ast$ to a map $M-\Sigma_i \to \#_n S^2\times S^1 - \cup_n S^2 \times \ast$, and get a degree one map from $M$ to $\#_n S^2\times S^1$. Now, we note that $\Sigma\times S^1$ has cut number at least $g$, by taking $g$ disjoint non-separating curves on $\Sigma$ and crossing them with $S^1$.

Remark on extending maps: Take a vertex in $M$, and connect it by $2n$ arcs to the surfaces $\Sigma_i$, one for each side of $\Sigma_i$ (which is possible by the non-separating assumption). Then the boundary of a tubular neighborhood of this graph and $\cup_i \Sigma_i$ gives a connected surface. We map do a similar thing in $\#_n S^2\times S^1$ with the surfaces $\cup_n S^2\times \ast$, where the boundary of the tubular neighborhood is a 2-sphere which bounds a ball. Extend the map on surfaces to a map on graphs, and then of a tubular neighborhood (getting a degree one map), then we may extend the map over the ball (just crush the degree one map of the surface to $S^2$ to a point to extend over the ball).

Comment: Thank you professor Agol. Would it be possible to say a few words about  or give a reference why it is possible to extend the map over the complement of $M-\Sigma_i$ in such a way that the map from M is degree one?

Comment: Thank you for your edit professor Agol. This is a very nice explanation.